# What color format should use to encode i420 frame converted by libyuv in mediacodec?

Tags: android-camera, android-mediacodec, yuv, libyuv

I converted nv21 frame to i420 frame with **libyuv**, and then encode the frame into a video file with **mediacodec**, the video looks strange. I use `COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar` and `COLOR_FormatYUV420Flexible` color format.[image: strange color]

So, what color format should i use to encode i420 frame converted by libyuv.

Comment: Most likely, your source frame was not **nv21**. Do you get the image from cameraX API?

Comment: Because this is a SDK project, it requires minSdkVersion 19, so, cameraX is not suitable for this project. I get camera's color format by calling `camera.parameters.previewFormat`, it return 17 - **ImageFormat.NV21**

Comment: The best example of using the old camera API and mediacodec is in [bigflake](https://bigflake.com/mediacodec/CameraToMpegTest.java.txt)

Comment: libyuv has methods to convert i420 to RGB and ARGB so you can try them